# How can I call a class/method in main project from library project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created two projects. One is a main application and second is just for the player.I am using player project as a library for the main project. Now, I have a feature in both project which allows users to share the video. I have done all sharing implementation and methods are in main project in a particular class called ShareActivity.class. Is there any way, I can use ShareActivity.class in Player library project?

I am thinking below solutions.

1) Should I use my library project as a jar file? Will it allow me to use a class from main project in library project?

2) Should I give reference of main project in a library project? I tried that but It is going in to infinite loop while building.

Please Advise!

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes that are in a library project in your main project, but not the other way round. If both apps need a particular feature, move it to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an explicit `Intent` in your library project (with a reference to `ShareActivity`), you could use an implicit `Intent` in your library project. Then your `ShareActivity` class would register to receive that implicit `Intent`. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving)